# Accumulated Depreciation of Assets on PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I have a problem table print out with asset accumulated depreciation on PHP, straight line method.

```
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "select current_value, salvage_value, useful_life, placed_service from assets");
    if(!$query){
        echo 'Could not run query b: ' . mysqli_error($connect);
        exit;
    }
    while($asset = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
    echo "assets :";
    print_r($asset);
    $month = 12; 
    $year = date('Y',strtotime($asset[3]));
    $first_year = $month - ((int)date('m',strtotime($asset[3]))-1);
    $last_year = $month - $first_year;
    $first = round((($asset[0] - $asset[1])/$asset[2])*(($first_year)/12),0);
    $last = round((($asset[0] - $asset[1])/$asset[2])*(($last_year)/12),0);
    $others = ($asset[0] - $asset[1])/$asset[2];

    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Book Value Year Start</th><th>Depreciation Expense</th><th>Accumulated Depreciation</th><th>Book Value Year End</th></tr>;
    for($i=$year;$i<=$year+$asset[2];$i++){
            //echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
            if ($i == $year){
                    //echo "<td>".$first."</td>";
                    $aset = $first;
            }
            elseif ($i == $year+$asset[2]){
                    //echo "<td>".$last."</td>";
                    $aset = $last;
            }
            else {
                    //echo "<td>".$others."</td>";
                    $aset = $others;
            }
                }
$current = $asset[0];
$total = 0;
$assets = array(array($i,$aset));
foreach($assets as $asets){
    echo "<tr><td>".$asets[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".number_format($current, 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
    echo "<td>".number_format($asets[1], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
    $total += $asets[1];
    echo "<td>".number_format($total, 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
    $current -= $asets[1];
    echo "<td>".number_format($current, 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
}
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    }
```

Here are result from @sean :

```
    Year    Book Value Year Start   Depreciation Expense    Accumulated Depreciation    Book Value Year End
    2014 100,000,000.00 8,250,000.00 8,250,000.00 91,750,000.00 
    2015 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 18,150,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2016 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 28,050,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2017 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 37,950,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2018 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 47,850,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2019 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 57,750,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2020 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 67,650,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2021 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 77,550,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2022 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 87,450,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2023 100,000,000.00 9,900,000.00 97,350,000.00 90,100,000.00 
    2024 100,000,000.00 1,650,000.00 99,000,000.00 98,350,000.00
```

Does anyone now how to create  accumulated depreciation table like below,

```
    Year     Book Value  Depreciation   Depreciation    Book Value
         Year Start      Expense    Accumulated Year End

    2014     100,000,000.000 8,250,000.00    8,250,000.00    91,750,000.00 
    2015     91,750,000.00   9,900,000.00    18,150,000.00   81,850,000.00 
    2016     81,850,000.00   9,900,000.00    28,050,000.00   71,950,000.00 
    2017     71,950,000.00   9,900,000.00    37,950,000.00   62,050,000.00 
    2018     62,050,000.00   9,900,000.00    47,850,000.00   52,150,000.00 
    2019     52,150,000.00   9,900,000.00    57,750,000.00   42,250,000.00 
    2020     42,250,000.00   9,900,000.00    67,650,000.00   32,350,000.00 
    2021     32,350,000.00   9,900,000.00    77,550,000.00   22,450,000.00 
    2022     22,450,000.00   9,900,000.00    87,450,000.00   12,550,000.00 
    2023     12,550,000.00   9,900,000.00    97,350,000.00   2,650,000.00 
    2024     2,650,000.00    1,650,000.00    99,000,000.00   1,000,000.00
```

I'am very appreciated if anyone know how make it on php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow your logic, but it looks like you just need to add 2 counter variables - (1) with the current value, and (2) the accumulated depreciation.

Here is a sample example -

```
$assets = array(
    array(2014,8250000),
    array(2015,9900000),
    array(2016,9900000),
    array(2017,9900000),
    array(2018,9900000),
    array(2019,9900000),
    array(2020,9900000),
    array(2021,9900000),
    array(2022,9900000),
    array(2023,9900000),
    array(2024,1650000));

$current = 100000000;
$total = 0;

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Book Value<br />Year Start</th><th>Depreciation<br />Expense</th><th>Depreciation<br />Accumulated</th><th>Book Value<br />Year End</th></tr>";

foreach($assets as $asset){
    echo "<tr><td>".$asset[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".number_format($current, 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
    echo "<td>".number_format($asset[1], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
    $total += $asset[1];
    echo "<td>".number_format($total, 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
    $current -= $asset[1];
    echo "<td>".number_format($current, 2, '.', ',')."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

---

based on your updated code try changing

```
$current = $asset[0];
```

to

```
if(!isset($current)) {$current = $asset[0];}
```

This way `$current` is only set on the 1st time in the loop, and not reset on each time through.

Comment: I follow your comment. I create one array from result. column year, depreciation_expense, depreciation_accumulated is OK but book_value_year_start and end have same value from first row till end row.

Comment: So, I need calculate book_value_year start in second row from book_value_year_end in first row and so on.

Comment: Since `$current = $asset[0];` is inside the loop it is being reset on each loop. Change `$current = $asset[0];` to `if(!isset($current)){$current = $asset[0];}`. This checks if `$current` isset, and only sets the value on the first loop.

Comment: sorry, I wanna ask how to insert into table from result with that code?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to output more columns once you've performed the necessary arithmetic.